# browser extension app - displaying Vue data() property in Chrome DevTools console

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have created a browser extension in Vue.js. I tried to display the Vue instance variables in the DevTool console. I am referring to the data() property. For it to work, I had to expose the Vue instance and data property to the window object manually

```
window.myVueApp = this;
window.myVueData = this.$data;
```

Then I was able to access from the DevTools Console using

```
window.myVueApp
window.myVueData
```

I read, exposing variables to the window object should be done carefully and primarily for development purposes. It could lead to lead to security vulnerabilities, issues etc.

I am a beginner with browser extensions. Can someone tell me what risks might arise?

Is there another way to view Vue data properties in teh devtool console in a browser extension without including the window object? I tried using Vue.js devtools with a browser extension, but it doesn't work here.